# gre division with remainder problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A certain number of toys were packed into $x$ boxes so that each box contained the same number of toys, with no toys left unpacked. If $3$ fewer boxes had been used instead, then $12$ toys would have been packed in each box, with $5$ toys left unpacked. What's the value of $x$?

$A. 11$

$B. 14$

$C. 28$

$D. 31$

$E. 34$

I'm not sure If I interpreted the problem correctly, but my approach as I will assume(guess) $x = 10$, then with $3$ fewer boxes, $x = 7$, so we packed $12$ toys in each box, each box has $1$ toy, left $5$ toys left unpacked. But none of these answer choices is $10$, so pretty sure I'm wrong.

I feel like this is just remainder problem, any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: With your guess, $x=10$, we'd get $12\times 7+5=89$ toys,  and $89$ is not divisible by $10$.

Comment: To solve the problem, let $y$ denote the number of toys.  Then $y=12\times (x-3)+5=12x-31$.  We need that to be divisible by $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Hi first time answering a question so bare with me

folowing from lulu's reponse you need

$$y=12(x-3)+5=12x-31$$

where $y$ denotes the total number of toys. To be divisible by $x$ one way to look at this is that

$$\frac{12x-31}{x}=12-\frac{31}{x}$$

Must be an integer.

The only number on that list which satisfies this is 31. So the answer is D.

Answer (score 1):

$x=31$ and the toys are $341$ because they say $$k x=12 (x-3)+5$$ where $k$ is the number of toys in the first boxing. Therefore
$$x=\frac{31}{12-k}$$
and the only integer value is $x=31$ for $k=11$.